# NIOS II system + PWM logic

Tags: fpga, nios

I am quite new designing systems with FPGAs, VHDL and NIOS II and this is my first post in this forum.

I am trying to develop a system with a NIOS II system + some PWMs developed using VHDL.
The problema is that I am not sure how to control this PWMs modelues with my system I mean, how to create the SIGNALs to comunicate this VHDL logic from NIOS II system.

First I though about PIO but those seem to be used to comunicate FPGA with external devices.

Another issue I have is that I am not sure how to use the UART implemented from Qsys and how to develop an application in C. I don't know what are the diferrent commands or directives to send or receive data.
I saw and write one example from a web I found but it is quite simple and doesn't provide enough info for my application.

Can anyone help with this??

Thanks!
Omar

Answer (score 0):

Two options are there,

1. Declaring the PIO, as you said earlier, it will work
2. Avalon interface to communicate.

For Avalon protocol, either it can be written by understanding the same or use template provided.

Altera is providing avalon memory mapped template for easier use.

https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/design-examples/intellectual-property/embedded/nios-ii/exm-avalon-memory-slave.html